# laravel: check the user received email today in laravel using carbon today

Tags: laravel, email, swiftmailer

I want to check that the user received email on that day or not. I already create DB table(name is **Email Save**) to detect that email sending or not. so i try to if statement in this

```php
if (EmailSave::where('created_at')-> Carbon::today()) {
```

this one didnt work. Anyone can help on this. I give my code over here

[image]

Comment: does it generate any errors

Comment: ya... its generate error 
 **Exception  : Property [Carbon] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.** 
showing the error @NipunTharuksha

Comment: Did you import the Carbon on the top of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your Syntax is wrong.

Change :

```
if (EmailSave::where('created_at')-> Carbon::today()) {
```

To:

```
if (EmailSave::where('created_at', Carbon::today())->exists()) {
```

#### Documentation:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates

Comment: Yes. I got it but after i use this my mail is not sending @Sapnesh Naik

Comment: Looks like you're having a new issue. Please post another question detailing your new issue.

Comment: if i use exists its causing problem